# Delphi Как выполнить дополнительный код при приведении типов присвоение переменных

Tags: delphi, классы, приведение-типов

Как в Delphi выполнить дополнительный код при приведении типов присвоение переменных?

`class operator` не помогает, или какой нужно использовать?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
type
   TRec2= record
     b:byte;
     s2:string;
     i2:integer;
   end;
   var R1,R2: TRec2;
begin
    R1:= R2;  // как при присвоении выполнить доп код?
end;
```

Comment: В Delphi 10.4 и выше используйте [class operator Assign](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Custom_Managed_Records#The_Assign_Operator)

Comment: 10.3 у меня....

Comment: ЕМНИП нужно для этой записи определить `class operator Implicit(a: TRec2): TRec2;`. Но я не уверен что он будет работать с этом же самым типом.